# 3D engine for iOS board game?

Tags: ios, 3d, game-engine

I in the early stage of developing a small board game for iPhone and I would like to show the board in 3D with textures, from a user-selectable point of view. The 3D view is expected to stay rather static, with the occasional animation when a move is played to show the played piece move on the board.

I am looking for suggestions for a 3D engine to use to do so. Wouldn't something like Unity be totally overkill for such a limited 3D use? Would it still be a good choice, even though I am probably going to use a very small subset of its features?

I realize that other similar questions have been asked, but as far as I can tell, they were about animated games, not board games, and I think that changes the context significantly.

A significant plus is for the final choice to support an easy path to an Android version.

The options I have been able to identify so far are:

- use OpenGL directly
- Unity: Pro: many, including Android support. Con: a tad expensive
- ShiVa3D: Pro: Android support. drawback: requires using Windows
- Cocos2D: pro: mature, large user base. Con: not 3D!
- cocos3D: pro: adds 3D to Cocos3D. Con: ?
- SIO2: pro: supports Android.
- iSGL3D. pro: open source, native Objective-C. Con: no Android support.

And I omitted a few more obscure (to me) ones.

I feel overwhelmed and I would appreciate some advice.

My background : I have significant experience with iOS development, but very little about 3D (though I have a strong math background).

Thanks.

Comment: One of the cons I've heard about cocos3D is that is it isn't a mature engine/library, and isn't nearly as supported as cocos2d is.  Unfortunately, I don't have a good answer to your question...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an open source product use iSGL3D, Cocos3D has many problems, it does not fully support animation, its POD importing is not complete, has not integrated with physics engine, does not support shaders and it is a one man product. iSGL3D has none of these problems.

Also note that there is some ways to integrating cocos2d with iSGL3D.

another point is that if you want to use open source product there is no difference between Cocos3d and iSGL3D. cocos3d has no android port, even porting cocos2d to android is not very straightforward and simple, and also note that there is no open source "very good" 3D library as I know.

I have published my 3D board game in App Store. Its name is "Spread Out 3D". It uses ISGL3D to render the board. Take a look at it http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spread-out-3d/id523404222?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Since you have very little experience of 3D (being good in Maths will help a lot), i would recommend Unity3D pro, it is expensive, but it is easy to use, probably the easiest engine you'll find, and it is usually considered the best engine among those which cost less than $1 million.

Also you would have found in your research that it has a great online reference and user manual and a good forum to help developers. Unity3d is what you should use in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for the opinion. I will definitely pay close attention to it.